# How to create nested JSON depending on values in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I do an API call and then I received a JSON, I need to modify that JSON based on their values, for example: if an id is equal to 0

The only way I've found to accomplish this is by adding multiple `if` statements and I want to do it dynamically by a function

This is my JSON

```
   {
      "Last_Scanned": 1,
      "Prefix_Title": 1 ,
      "First_Name": 0,
      "Family_Name": 1,
      "Job_Title": 1, 
      "Company": 0,
      "Address_1": 1, 
      "Zip_Code": 1, 
      "City": 1,
      "Country_Code": 0
    }
```

An this is how I'm trying to filter by the ones that have a value equals to 0, the `response` is the original `json`

```js
let selectedfield:any = [response]
        selectedfield.forEach(element => {
          avoidFields =  selectedfield.map((x:any) => { 
            if(x.Last_Scanned== 0){
              avoidFields.push(Object.keys(x.Person_Id))
              console.log(Object.keys(x))
            }

          })
        })
```

The result I'm looking for is for having something like this

```
   {
      "First_Name": 0,
      "Company": 0,
      "Country_Code": 0
    }

OR

   {
      "First_Name",
      "Company",
      "Country_Code"
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this satisfy what you're trying to do?

```js
// sample entry.
let sampleObject = {
  "Last_Scanned": 1,
  "Prefix_Title": 1 ,
  "First_Name": 0,
  "Family_Name": 1,
  "Job_Title": 1, 
  "Company": 0,
  "Address_1": 1, 
  "Zip_Code": 1, 
  "City": 1,
  "Country_Code": 0
};

// destination object.
let newObject = {};

// iterate through the object properties.
for (let prop in sampleObject) {
  // add to the new object if value is zero.
  if (sampleObject[prop] === 0) {
    newObject[prop] = 0; // or any value you want to set.
  }
}

console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this suggestion:

```
function convertObject(obj){
    return Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(a).filter(arr => arr[1]===0)
           );
}
```

Explanation:

- `Object.entries(a)` entries will return array of [key,Value]
- `.filter(arr => arr[1]===0)` will filter entries [key,value] which has 0 values
- finally we convert it to an object with `Object.fromEntries(..)`